# HTML button on click show overlay layer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show an overlay for full page when button on click. I intended to add an iframe in the content div for pop up. Here is my HTML:

And CSS to show and hide the overlay:

```css
.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 1200px;">


<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Show Overlay</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
  <div class="content">
   Content
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qm1pqunz/53/)

However, there is a slight issue with the styling. The overlay does not cover the part below when scrolling down. It only covers the part before start scrolling down. I tried to set the height to 100% but to no futile.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`. position `absolute` set an auto height based on window height not body.

```css
.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 1200px;">


  <div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Show Overlay</a>
  </div>

  <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
      <div class="content">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```